# Passing dynamic field names to jquery's each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a field name dynamically to my function in order for my form to use autocomplete. I then call this function in my page but I keep getting an error and I think it's because it's trying to get the column property literally as opposed to dynamically.

In PHP I could do something like {$fieldName}. Is there a javascript equivalent? Or am I getting this horribly wrong?

```
// Call to function index.php
inputSuggetion('input.search', 'http://myapi.com/endpoint', 'title')


// Function
function inputSuggestion(element, endPoint, fieldName) {
    $(element).on("keydown", function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                q: $(element).val()
            },
            url: endPoint,
            success: function(data) {
                var apiCollection = [];
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    apiCollection.push(value.fieldName);
                });
                $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
                    source: apiCollection
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the sample json Data that you receive on success?

Comment: What is the error? Why are you initializing autocomplete inside `keydown` event handler? Plugin already has internal key handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right then you want to get the value of field '`title`' from your Json data and this field name '`title`' will be passed to the function dynamically.
In this case your syntax to get the value from `json` is wrong.

you just need to change following line of code:

from :

```
apiCollection.push(value.fieldName);
```

to :

```
apiCollection.push(value[fieldName]);
```

let me know in case of any issue.